# Диапазон значений координат геолокации LocationManager в Android

Tags: android, геолокация, locationmanager

В каком диапазоне возвращаются широта и долгота геолокации LocationManager в Android?

Comment: В смысле в каком диапазоне? В диапазоне координат широты и долготы.

Comment: Интересует диапазон значений широты и долготы от и до. То есть в какой системе измерений возвращаются эти значения? Существуют разные системы геологических координат и диапазоны там разные. Например, от 0 до 360 или от -180 до 180 и т.д.

Answer (score 1):

**Latitude**, в градусах. Значение в промежутке **[-90, 90]**.

**Longitude**, в градусах. Значение в промежутке **[-180, 180)**.